# Modify Google Forms confirmation page to display the time stamp using App Script .gs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I watched this youtube [video][1] which is in Hindi. I don't understand what he says but see what he does and that it works. So I tried to replicate to get the same result: for the Confirmation Page of a Google Form to display the date and time. I actually prefer to get the submission time stamp, but perhaps it doesn't matter.
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oC4Os1N5Tjs

So I wrote this in Apps Script, copying directly from the video (shown at **9:40** of the runtime):

```
function confirmationPage1() {
  let form = FormApp.openById("1fbdR0F8zBFyn_oz1P4uSdRUBzEAp3EsfemB44LiDaXE");
  let date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  Logger.log(date)
  form.setConfirmationMessage()
}
```

This doesn't work, and it's not telling me the reason: "other error".
So I tried something else using a method which works for generating an email that includes the time stamp, like this:

```
function confirmationPage2(e) {
  var formResponse = e.response;
  var date = e.response.getTimestamp().toString().substring(0, 24);
  let form = FormApp.openById("1fbdR0F8zBFyn_oz1P4uSdRUBzEAp3EsfemB44LiDaXE");
  Logger.log(date)
  form.setConfirmationMessage()
}
```

Again, same result - doesn't work. Any help - greatly appreciated!

Bonus: at the end, I don't really just want to display the time stamp in the confirmation page, but a link that includes the time stamp (a link to another google form that's pre-filled with the time stamp of this one, so that I know which respondent continued to the next one. But this should not be difficult, if I manage to get it to display the time stamp in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Instead of this:

`form.setConfirmationMessage()`

#### Try this:

`form.setConfirmationMessage(date)`

As for the second script, add a trigger that runs  `confirmationPage2`, `Event Source = From Form`  `Event type = on form submit` Otherwise time will not change for each submission.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Yancy. Of course both versions work, but for the second one (which I went with) I actually just defined the event source in Rules, rather than in the code. It would have helped if I watched the video 10 seconds further where the author corrects his code - oops... Also, for other people reading this, please be aware that Google Forms Confirmation Page will not display anything from the current submission - only from the last submission - because the Confirmation Page gets pre-loaded the moment the form is opened.