# I am trying to do first and last name validation of a google form, using Apps Scripts connected to a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Question 1 and 2 of the google form are first and last name respectively. I am trying to only let people submit names that are listed in a google sheet. Is this possible. I am having issues getting the responses to form stop when incorrect.

```
This is the code that I used. I was having issues with the var first name getting set to responce[1]

Is this even possible to do, if so is there a better way to do this/ how do I fix it.

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var responses = e.values;
  var firstName = responses[1]; // Assuming "First Name" is the first question in the form
  var lastName = responses[2];  // Assuming "Last Name" is the second question in the form

  // Check if the submitted name is in the Google Sheet
  if (!isNameInSheet(firstName, lastName)) {
    form.setCustomClosedFormMessage("The entered name does not match any in the list.");
    form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
    // Display an error message popup
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Error', 'The entered name does not match any in the list.', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}

function isNameInSheet(firstName, lastName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(`My google sheet ID`).getActiveSheet(); // Replace with your spreadsheet ID
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:B' + sheet.getLastRow()); // Assuming names are in columns A (first name) and B (last name), starting from row 2
  var data = range.getValues();

  // Loop through the range to check if the name is present
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var sheetFirstName = data[i][0].toLowerCase();
    var sheetLastName = data[i][1].toLowerCase();
    
    if (sheetFirstName === firstName.toLowerCase() && sheetLastName === lastName.toLowerCase()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: It depends upon what you mean by submit.  By the time you get a onFormSubmit the form data has already been submitted.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, in theory, to use Google Apps Script to reject invalid submissions with Google Forms, but there are some limitations to how you can notify the user that their submission is invalid from the Google Forms interface. Here are some options to consider:

### Alternative Options

*[OPTION 1]*

- Validate & notify the user via after submission via [setConfirmationMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setConfirmationMessage(String)).

### Sample Script

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const sheetId = e.source.getDestinationId();
  // Gets an array of the form's responses.
  const formResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  const fullName = formResponses.filter(response => /^(First Name|Last Name)$/.test(response.getItem().getTitle()))
    .map(response => response.getResponse());

  checkNames(sheetId, fullName.join(' '));
}

function checkNames(sheetId, fullName) {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  const listOfNames = sheet.getSheetByName('List Names').getDataRange().getValues();

  const remove = () => {
    const submissionSheet = sheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
    const row = submissionSheet.getLastRow();
    submissionSheet.deleteRow(row);
    console.log('Rejected submission!');
    form.setConfirmationMessage('Invalid!\nThe entered name does not match any in the list.');
    return;
  };

  const allowed = () => {
    console.log('allowed!');
    form.setConfirmationMessage('Thank you for submitting!');
    return;
  };

  //Validation to check if submission will be allowed or removed
  listOfNames.filter(name => name.join(' ') == fullName).length <= 0 ? remove() : allowed();

}
```

**How to run and test the sample script:**

1. Execute the function 'checkNames' one time from the Apps Script editor to first initialize the authentication & scopes required to automatically run the script.
2. Setup the form submit trigger from the editor and add the `onFormSubmit` function.

### Demo

**Test `List Names` sheet:**
[image]

**Sample Invalid submission:**
[image]

**Forms responses during invalid submission:**
[image]

### Current limitation of this method

In my experience, there is a current challenge in using "setConfirmationMessage". In this use case, we want it to display different after submission messages dynamically. However, the [Google Form confirmation page will not display anything from the current submission - only from the last submission - because the Confirmation Page gets pre-loaded the moment the form is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72396753/15384825), as seen below:

> *Here, we input a valid name, but the confirmation still shows the previous invalid confirmation message. However, when we resubmit another valid name, it shows the valid confirmation message from the previous submission.*
> [image]

---

*[OPTION 2]*

- Validate & notify the user via email.

You may also circumvent this limitation by sending an email notification rather than an after-submission confirmation message. You may need to enable the "[collect verified emails](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706#zippy=%2Ccollect-respondents-email-addresses)" option in the Form settings. Here is a revised sample script:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const sheetId = e.source.getDestinationId();
  // Gets an array of the form's responses.
  const formResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  const fullName = formResponses.filter(response => /^(First Name|Last Name)$/.test(response.getItem().getTitle()))
    .map(response => response.getResponse());
  const email = e.response.getRespondentEmail();

  checkNames(sheetId, fullName.join(' '), email);
}

function checkNames(sheetId, fullName, email) {
  try{MailApp.sendEmail();}catch{} //For Authorization
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  const listOfNames = sheet.getSheetByName('List Names').getDataRange().getValues();

  const sendEmailNotif = () => {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Invalid name input', 'The name you submitted in the form is invalid. Please fill up the form with the correct credentials.');
    console.log('Sent email to ' + email);
  }

  const remove = () => {
    const submissionSheet = sheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
    const row = submissionSheet.getLastRow();
    submissionSheet.deleteRow(row);
    console.log('Rejected submission!');
    sendEmailNotif();
    return;
  };

  const allowed = () => {
    console.log('allowed!');
    return;
  };

  //Validation to check if submission will be allowed or removed
  listOfNames.filter(name => name.join(' ') == fullName).length <= 0 ? remove() : allowed();

}
```

Comment: @William Spear Feel free to ask any questions you may have about the matter. I will do my best to provide you with additional information or clarification.